# Toggling between display block and display none of SVG elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a javascript script that is trying to change the display properties of individual SVG elements in one fairly large SVG image. I had previously had this working but when copied it into this file it has failed to work. I have tried incorporating the script into the head or the body to no avail.
The javascript section is as follows

```
  <script>
<![CDATA[
    var transMatrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0];
    function toggle(id)
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if ( e.style.display == "none" ) 
        {
            e.style.display = "block";
        }
        else if ( e.style.display == "block" ) 
        {
            e.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    function multi_toggle(list)
    {
        for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
        {
            toggle(list[i]);
        }
    }
    ]]>
</script>
```

And in the control elements I have the attribute

```
onclick="multi_toggle(['tube-map','suburban-map'])"
```

Any help would be very apprechiated

Comment: What is the problem? Any errors? What is the onclick attached to?

Comment: Do those id's actually exist?  If you call this in your console what happens? document.getElementById('tube-map');

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. The problem was inkscape setting the display attribute to inline rather than block. so nothing wrong with the code as posted above